# Travel social network database design

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, social-networking, database-schema

I'm creating a database for a travel social network application that I'll build next. This is my work so far. Table names are pretty self-explanatory. My question is - is this good approach? I would like to hear your opinions and suggestions to make this model better in terms of data organization and performance.

Images:

[Left part of ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwTM2.jpg)

[Right part of ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWfsx.jpg)

Is it a good approach to use generalization in `things_to_do -> events|places -> ...` branch? As for now I will have to make at least 3 joins to get basic data about specific place, and even more for other information. Should I make seperate tables for every `things_to_do` and new many-to-many connection tables for that each table to increase performance? When I say performance, I emphasize search queries. How can I make this scalable? Should I use other database model?

Comment: This is way too vague of a question. You should make it more precise or it risks getting closed pretty darn quick.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have made it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The term "generalization" and the counterpart term "specialization" is generally used when an ER diagram depicts the conceptual model of the data.  A conceptual model depicts the semantics of the data with reference to the subject matter, without prejudging which design is going to be better.  A conceptual ERD really pertains to data analysis, and not database design.

Your diagram, on the other hand, is clearly a design document and not an analysis document.  It reflects your intent to build a relational database, rather than some other kind.  So your boxes represent tables, rather than more abstract "entitties" or relationships among entities.

Generalization/specialization has a counterpart in object modeling, known as either type/subtype or class/subclass design.  When it comes time to implement a class/subclass pattern in the form of tables tied together by foregin  keys, the design is not intuitively obvious, and this case is often passed over in database design tutorials.

You should visit these three tags, and click on "learn more" to get an outline of three techniques you might want to think about:  [single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key).

You'll find a good balance between performance, ease of programming, and future adapatbility.